# Unity3D EasyTouch challenge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just purchased EasyTouch 3.1 plugin for Unity3D and i just can't get EasyTouch to recognize an object with a collider from a script attached to an empty object.

If there is anyone with experience with EasyTouch I would really appreciate some help.

Here is the code i use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class tet1 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Subscribe to events
    void OnEnable(){
        EasyTouch.On_TouchStart += On_TouchStart;
    }
    // Unsubscribe
    void OnDisable(){
        EasyTouch.On_TouchStart -= On_TouchStart;
    }
    // Unsubscribe
    void OnDestroy(){
        EasyTouch.On_TouchStart -= On_TouchStart;
    }
    // At the touch beginning
    public void On_TouchStart(Gesture gesture){
        // Verification that the action on the object
        print ("YEP: " + gesture.pickObject.name);
    }
}
```

I get the following message when i click on the object:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I get it on the following line: "print ("YEP: " + gesture.pickObject.name);" so I guess i am doing something wrong with this line of code that i cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with that plugin, but it seems that you are registering to any touch event, and then, on the handler, you don't check if an object is touched.

You should go with

```
public void On_TouchStart(Gesture gesture)
{
    // ensure an object is touched
    if (gesture.pickObject != null) 
    {
        // Verification that the action on the object
        print ("YEP: " + gesture.pickObject.name);
    }
}
```